# How to parse and print a matching search in a line of text, plus the next 2 lines after a match in Python

Tags: python, parsing

the Code below works great for matching and printing out a single matching line, but I also need to see the data on the next line in a Cisco configuration file.

```
fopen = open('running-config.cfg',mode='r+')

fread = fopen.readlines()

x = input("Enter the search string: ")

for line in fread:
    
      if x in line:
          
          print(line)
```

If my search is "server" in the example below, how do I print the next line in the code above which is "host 10.3.59.119" . If I could have both lines, this would be huge.

```
object network server
 host 10.3.59.119
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add a counter outside the for loop setting it to zero. If there is a match found set it to two. Now add an if statement which checks if counter > 0. If so print the line and decrease the counter.

Something like:

```py
counter = 0
for line in fread:
    if x in line:
        print(line)
        counter = 2
    elif counter > 0: # elif because otherwise the line would be printed twice
        print(line)
        counter -= 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I tried these exactly as you have here, it gives me too many other records, but when it does find the string I'm looking for, it does give the next 2 lines. I really need to just get the my search string data and the next 2 lines, nothing else. Please test it if you can and validate what I'm seeing

Comment: @jwkersey today I tested my code. I only used your code above the for loop and my for loop. It worked perfectly fine. Make sure you have copied my code correctly.

Comment: It now works great after adding "counter -= 1" at the bottom. Thanks !